# How can I remember to build Supply Depots all game?

Tags: starcraft-2

What tricks and tips have you employed to keep building Supply Depots all game? I've tried keeping one SCV idle to remember, but I keep getting supply locked.

Comment: Tattoo the inside of your eye-lids?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Develop a mental checklist.

[Day[9] has an excellent video](https://youtu.be/m36BSwQY0Ag) focused on encouraging you to keep thinking about a small series of specific tasks or thoughts throughout the entirety of the game. When you start off, your mental checklist should probably be limited to about 4 main things:

1. Are my resources high?
2. Am I about to be supply blocked?
3. Am I building things that help towards my overall strategy?
4. Is there stuff happening on my mini-map?

Because of the way that the HUD is arranged, this means that ideally your eyes should constantly be darting back and forth between the top right and bottom left corners of the screen.

So to address your specific problem of being supply blocked consistently, you should create a *mental trigger* that associates a common task with checking your supply, so that every time you perform that task you don't even have to think before your eyes dart to the end of the screen. In this context, the action that makes the most sense to associate with being supply blocked is making a unit. In other words, **everytime you make a unit, check your supply count**.

It'll be difficult to get used to and you'll still slip up occasionally, but if you keep on trying to remember this, eventually you'll develop the habits necessary to keep on checking your supply count and thereby remembering to get that supply depot up on time.

Also keep in mind that as you expand and make more production facilities, your supply will go up faster, so while a single SCV producing depots will work for one base, eventually you'll need to keep two SCVs making depots in order to keep up with your supply as you expand.

Comment: Strongly agree with this. It's not about having some trick to remember to do it, it should just be instinct.

Comment: @Wipqozn though checking my supply count every time I make a unit is indeed a "trick" that will help develop the instinct.

Comment: @Soup I was only referring to not having a trick to remember to re-supply, that it should become instinct - using tricks to make to it become instinct is completely different; at least I consider it to be.

Answer (score 6):

Players that often get supply blocked tend to do it like this: First they get supply blocked, then in a panic build 3 supply depots immediately, and that *buys them enough time to forget* to build more later, and the cycle continues.

It's important to **get into a rhythm of building supply depots**. Just as you must get into many rhythms in sc2. Building supply depots is an essential part of your macro game, the little brother to constant unit production.

Answer (score 3):

I've tried to put a white sticker on the top of the screen. You will always see it. It is very annoying... and once you see it (each 10 seconds) you will remember that you need to check you supply count....

I hoped it will help a lot to keep supply enough...

but that sticker is SO annoying, that you can NOT play with him at all...

P.S. I would consider that answer as "ANTI" answer. The only positive thing could be extracted from it is the following: there are no any easy way... and see other answers, they are pretty good. And I would accept tenfour suggestion as an answer.

Comment: Very creative. I like the idea.

Comment: does not work, due to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inattentional_blindness

Answer (score 2):

You can install program from [sc2drill](http://sc2drill.com) to notify you regularly check your limit

I recommend use interval of 30-60 seconds for this. As from my experience after 5-10 games  you'll find that you have a sense of rhythm and almost no supply blocks

Comment: and when the reminders stop, you also stop